# How do two entities sync Character Encodings without prior interaction via HTTP request?

Tags: http, character-encoding, httprequest

So client A has never communicated with server B before, but for the first time ever it sends server B an HTTP request. Assuming that they each use different character encodings locally, how are they able to understand each other if the raw bytes sent by A over the air are parsed by B to be different characters than A intended? In other words, if A sends "hello" to B, B might parse the message as empty text because they have different encodings so how is this fixed?